# Deleting srt files from vlc app in iPad Mini

Tags: ipad, vlc

I have installed VLC app in my iPad Mini and have been enjoying movies. But the srt files I have transferred to my iPad cannot be removed even after I have deleted the movies from my iPad.

Before there were only some files, so it was not a problem for me but now it's been a mess. I tried to delete it from the iPad but the files aren't visible there. I don't have Macbook. I tried to delete via Windows, but the delete option doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

So you have lot of subtitles hanging around loosely. There are two ways you can remove these annoying creatures. I will discuss both of them, use whichever suits you best.

1. Delete and re-install the VLC app.
2. Take a deep breath, this is going to be long. There is a work-around that I've found and works 9/10 times.

**Theory:**

What VLC does in the background is that, it deletes the subtitles files automatically  whenever you delete the parent video file, provided that the video and the subtitle have same name.

For example, if your video file is named "test.mkv" then the subtitle file should be "test.srt"

**What you need:**

1. A video clip, format doesn't matter, and smaller the size is
   better as it will take less time to get copied.
2. iTunes

**Procedure:**

1. Connect your iPad to your computer and go to iTunes.
2. In iTunes, go the "Apps" section of your iPad and find your way to VLC.
3. Copy all the parent-less subtitles to one folder in your desktop.
4. Create copies of the video clip as many as the number of subtitles present in that folder. For example, If you have 4 subtitles, then you create 4 copies of the same video clip.
5. Rename each video clip to one of the subtitle. Take caution while renaming, don't change the extension/format of the video clip.
6. Once you have the video clips renamed, copy the video clips to back to VLC.
7. Save and eject the iPad from iTunes and computer.
8. Go the VLC app in your iPad and start deleting those renamed video clips.

So, as per the theory, when you delete the video clip, VLC will delete its subtitle as well simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect your mobile device to a larger device to delete those files as you will require iTunes:

1. Connect your mobile device (iPad or iPhone) to a laptop or desktop PC;
2. Open iTunes;
3. Make sure the device (iPad or iPhone) trusts the laptop or desktop PC and is able to communicate with it;
4. In iTunes:

   1. Click on the small icon of the connected mobile device (e.g. small iPad icon) on the top;
   2. Click on **Apps** under **Settings**;
   3. Scroll down till the bottom and click on **VLC** in **Apps**;
   4. Select the file(s) you want to delete in the right section (**VLC Documents**);
   5. Press the **Del** button on your keyboard;
   6. Confirm clicking on **Delete**;